# Analogue of complex projective space, replacing GL1 with GLn

Tags: vector-bundles, projective-space

$\mathbb{CP}^1$ can be formed from $\mathbb{C}^\times = \text{GL}_1$ by gluing $\mathbb{C}$ by itself along $\mathbb{C}^\times$, a pushout of $1/z,z : \mathbb{C}^\times \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

I am hoping that someone can help me to figure out a simpler form for the coequilizer $\text{Id}, \text{Inv} : \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$. Call this $\mathbb{CP}^{1,n}$.

Just as $\mathbb{C}^\times$-principal bundles correspond to both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{CP}^1$ bundles, it would also be nice to know whether $\mathbb{CP}^{1,n}$-bundles correspond to principal $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$-bundles.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> To clarify, by "coequalizer" do you mean the result gluing two copies of the space of $n \times n$ complex matrices by identifying each invertible matrix $A$ in one copy with $A^{-1}$ in the other copy? (If so, I suspect the result is not a manifold except in the $1 \times 1$ case, though I don't have a proof offhand.)